# Getting Error : Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in jquery-ui.js and jquery.dataTables.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

[image]
[enter image description here](https://i.sta)

[image]ck.imgur.com/ooq5Y.png

[image]

I am getting these errors and cannot figure out why its happeining,as it was not showing earlier.
Does anyone have any idea about this issue.Please help me.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Remove the ng-jq from the html tag,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">
```

Answer (score 0):

This is always a flashing sign for 'a wrong file got delivered'. JavaScript files cannot begin with `<`, but almost all html files do.

In this case the `index.html` is being delivered. I am guessing you are using either the angular router or the ui-router and have defined something along the lines of `$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('index.html');`.

This is what's being executed here. As to why: no idea, we have too little of your code to judge on that.

Answer (score 0):

You are sending html files with a javascript extension rename your file to html extension

Answer (score 0):

it's not for your html code,
it is because of your js code and can't see in log which part of your code has problem.
only solution is => check again your currently added js code